# Spring does not try to inject values to constructor-arg placeholder

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, constructorargument

I have this strange problem, that Spring does not try to pass defined values to placeholder in constructor-arg. Currently it is defined as `${myProperty}` , but I could write anything there, there are no errors. It just passes the literal string `${myProperty}` to the bean constructor, otherwise the configuration seems to work perfectly.

My beans.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <context:property-placeholder order="1" properties-ref="propertiesBean" />

  <bean id="propertiesBean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">

   <property name="properties">
      <props>
        <prop key="myProperty">Foo</prop>
      </props>
  </property>

  </bean>

  <bean id="wrapperBean" class="springapp.bean.Wrapper">    
    <constructor-arg value="${myProperty}">          
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing with this configuration. Maybe it is something obvious, I don't have much experience with Spring. Using Spring version 3.2.x and WildFly 8.1 as a container.

EDIT:

The beans.xml is loaded like this:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TestServlet.class);

  private XmlBeanFactory factory;

  public void init() throws ServletException {
    ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("beans.xml", TestServlet.class.getClassLoader());
    factory = new XmlBeanFactory(resource);
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Wrapper bean = (Wrapper) factory.getBean("wrapperBean");
    String value = bean.inner.value;
    resp.getWriter().print(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you loading this xml file?

Comment: Edited the post, included the loading servlet

Comment: Use an `ApplicationContext` not a `BeanFactory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loading is flawed you should use an `ApplicationContext` instead of a `BeanFactory`.

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TestServlet.class);

  private ApplicationContext ctx;

  public void init() throws ServletException {
    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Wrapper bean = ctx.getBean("wrapperBean", Wrapper.class);
    String value = bean.inner.value;
    resp.getWriter().print(value);
  }
}
```

For the differences check [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory).